# Is there an open database to query bitcoin transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, wallet

My goal is to get all addresses with a balance of more than 0.01 BTC. In order to get this data, I have to sync the full bitcoin node but I want to avoid it. Maybe there is any open SQL or MongoDB database somewhere. The speed is important.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/addresses?q=balance(1000000..)&s=balance(asc)# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud provides a dataset for most public blockchains, including bitcoin. You can directly query the dataset via their BigQuery Tool - you can use standard SQL

Bitcoin Dataset on GCP:

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bitcoin/crypto-bitcoin?filter=solution-type:dataset&id=7fd60425-cb95-4a58-b59f-ab3789642844